# I have 2 multiple selects in table but the value is changing for all of them

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have a material-UI multi select in a table. I want to select one option for one item and and along with it I have JSON in which I want to show multi-select from one key value pair like: `"groupImportedAs": "Super / Normal"`. Here `super/normal` are both the multi-select option to be shown in the field.

But whenever I try to select one option, the options are changing for all. I want to select one option for one item at a time. But I get the value changed of multi-select all of them at once, which I don't want.

Also, I want to get the `"groupImportedAs": "Super / Normal"` from the JSON and get the value.

Here is my JSON:

```
{
  "groupsList": [
    {
      "groupId": 1,
      "groupName": "Arial Team",
      "groupImportedAs": "Normal",
      "groupDistinguishName": ""
    },
    {
      "groupId": 3,
      "groupName": "Genesis II",
      "groupImportedAs": "Super",
      "groupDistinguishName": ""
    }
 ]
```

[image]

```
import { FormControl, MenuItem, Select, Table, TableBody, 
 TableCell, TableHead, TableRow } from '@material- 
ui/core';

const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState('');

const handleChange = (event) => {
        setSelected(event.target.value); 
}
<Select
         name="userRoles"
         id="userRoles"
         value={selected}
         name="select_importas"
         onChange={handleChange}
     >
     <MenuItem value="normal_Group">Normal Group</MenuItem>
     <MenuItem value="super_Group">Super Group</MenuItem>
</Select>
```

I want to select the options from JSON to show in multi-select as I have GET API and change the option for one item at a time.

Comment: can you share more parts of your code or a small online reproduction of your problem? in your code I can only see one `Select` component now

Comment: I have shared the code. or can you do one thing to come online on google meet ??

Comment: Can you create a demo in the sandbox?

Comment: yes sure. I'm creating wait